# Contact Form 7 in vs code

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form

```
[contact-form-7 id="2722" title="Contact form 1"]
```

I want to write it down to vs code but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is something that can easily be found in the documentation for including a shortcode. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in php file with do_shortcode function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2722" title="Contact form 1"]');
```